# How to run Arc Hydro in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.2, arc-hydro

I tried to run a ModelBuilder program but it gave the error below.

[image]

I am working in ArcMap 10.2, windows 7 64 bit pro and the raster format is Grid.

When installing ArcGIS 10.2, it required me to activate extension (customize/extension/select all extension).

After the install the Arc Hydro toolbar does not add to extension to enable it to be active.

I think the above error is because Arc Hydro has not been activated.

What is your opinion?

Comment: Some ArcHydro tools require Standard and Advanced license (ArcEditor, ArcInfo).  If you do not have an Advanced license, you will not be able to run some of the tools.